# How to find whether an executable is in the PATH without iterating all the folders on the path (or executing it)

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, path, filesystems

I know file operations are rather non-standard between OS's and API's but I would like to discover whether an executable (named at run time) exists in the path.

This is a validation of user input and later on the app is called using

```
        ProcessStartInfo ^processStartInfo = gcnew ProcessStartInfo("ReallyCool.exe");
        Process ^process = gcnew Process();
        process->StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        bool processStarted = process->Start();
```

this throws only when it comes to the last line above.

Does anyone know how I can verify the file is there before taking the risk of actually executing it or am I being a naif by allowing users to run '.exes' through my app?

As per title, I am keen to avoid searching every directory on the path explicitly if possible. Nor am I certain how I could obtain the Windows path from .NET coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the file is there, use `bool doesFileExist = System.IO.File.Exists(path);`

I doubt there is an easy way to know if it is a valid executable without trying to run it.

Comment: thanks, one remaining complexity is providing each directory in the path but your code makes things much easier for me.

Comment: do you need to to look for a file in subfolders of a given path?

Comment: I need to look at the exact path the client PC searches for executables. I think it is something like %PATH% in DOS shells but I don't know how to get it for any Windows PC, programmatically, using WinAPI or .NET.

Comment: `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")`